# Sort big binary file by length

Tags: linux, bash

How can I sort big binary file by length? The file size is 256GB.

Expected input:

```
aaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Expected output:

```
aaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The file contains non-prinable characters and NULL-bytes.

I use `cat file.txt | grep -aE '^.$' >> /temp`, `cat file.txt | grep -aE '^.{2}$' >> /temp`, `...`, but it works too slow. All lines are unique.

A line is a set of characters between each `\n`. In the input file each "line" is less than 512 bytes, so there are no big chunks. The character `\n` always represent a break.

Comment: Sort by length of what? There's no concept of "lines" nor "records" in a binary file

Comment: By the length of the line. A line is a set of characters between each `\n`.

Comment: If it has "lines", it is not a binary file anymore. So you want to say, that you have a file of **arbitrary** data bytes, and some of those bytes happen to be 0A (hexadecimal), and these bytes serve as record separators, and you want to rearrange the file by the length of those records?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this purpose. In a binary file a `\n` does not necessarily represent a line break. It may appear anywhere as part of binary numbers, machine code or whatever data is stored in the file. Please add details about the type of file you want to process and what you want to achieve with this sorting.

Comment: This is absolutely correct! Also we can assume that the length of each "record" is less than 512 bytes.

Comment: If the first line is "aaaa" and the second line is "bbbb" (same length), what should the output be? Do you care if "bbbb" is output first?

Comment: Can you describe why you refer to these as "binary files"?

Comment: Be aware that any file that contains NULs is not a valid text file per POSIX and so YMMV with what any text-processing tool (awk, sed, grep, etc.) does with such a file. Some tools are written in C where internally `NUL` represents the end of a string and so they cannot store input containing NULs in strings. You should be OK using GNU tools for this but make sure to check the man page for any tool to see if it says it can handle NULs in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton I just checked with GNU `awk` vs. macOS `awk` and, indeed, the latter apparently cuts the records on NUL while the former does not.

Comment: you mention characters and bytes but it's not clear (to me) if you're looking for length in terms of the number of characters or length in terms of the number of bytes; eg, a UTF-8 character may have length of 1 but consist of 3 bytes

Answer (score 3):

As usuall:

1. Add each line length to the line.
2. Sort by line length.
3. Remove line length.

For example:

```
LC_ALL=C awk '{print length($0), $0}' inputfile | sort -k1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

> The file size is 256GB.

You might be interested in GNU `sort` options like `--batch-size` or `--compress-program` or `--buffer-size` etc.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Ed in comments, if your file contains NUL characters some tools will not cut them in *lines* on newline characters. The `awk` that comes with macOS, for instance, truncates the input records on the first encountered NUL, while GNU `awk` does not.

So, if your `awk`, `sort` and `cut` support NUL, you can try:

```
awk '{print length "\t" $0}' foo.bin | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

If you want to preserve the original order among equal length lines, and your `sort` is GNU `sort`:

```
awk '{print length "\t" $0}' foo.bin | sort -snk1,1 | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**edit:** incorporated @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub tips</sub>

If you have enough disk space available then you can create an output file for each line-size, with alphabetically-sorted filenames, making it possible to use a glob for getting them in the right order:

```bash
LANG=C awk '{print > (sprintf("part_%06d",length($0)))}' bigFile.bin
```

**remarks:**

- If the input data can include a `NUL` byte then you'll have to use an `awk` that can handle it, for ex. GNU `awk`.
- As the lines are topped at 512 bytes, neither GNU `awk` nor Linux should complain about the number of FDs that are opened simultaneously by `awk`.

---

Then, if you really need the result to be in a single file, you can concatenate the "parts" like this:

```bash
cat part_* > sorted_bigFile.bin
```

Comment: Read carefully `sort`'s manpage (and [KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76929140/1765658)!) There is no need of big RAM for sorting big files!!

Comment: But you shown *another way of thinking*!, interesting!! But you could: `awk '{ file=sprintf("file-%06d.part",length($0));print >file}'; cat file-*.part`, (so you don't need to use `sort -n | xargs cat` )

Comment: Using a big enough 0-padded integer will make things simpler indeed; but a `printf file-*.part | xargs cat` might still be required.

Comment: No: `cat file-*,part` will be enough if you pad small numbers by `0`, using `file-%08d.part`. The sorting will be done by bash.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I included your tips in my answer

Comment: *`# OR, if you get an "Argument list too long":`*  I think if your list is based on length line, you won't ever reach maximum [tag:bash] line length (which is lot higher than POSIX shell)!!

Comment: Please tests! `echo 'Hello good world!'{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}{,,}|wc` will generate and **execute** a simple [tag:bash] line of *`27.37Mb`*!! I can't imagine a list of files *`part_XXXXXX`* bigger than 27Mb!!

Comment: ... if you could write `printf '%s\n' part_*`, you could write `cat part_*`!  Your `printf  ... | xargs` is clearly useless!!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub You're right, it's highly unlikely to fail with OP's requirements; I only start getting an argument list too long with `part_{00000000..00095124}`

Comment: Full script with `ZStandard` compression: [sortByLengthWithCompression](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/sortByLengthWithCompression.txt)